# Android Tests: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-testing, instrumented-test

I have created this android test:

```
package fr.tisseo.android.repository.productlocalization.tests

import androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
class TodeleteTest {
    @Test
    fun testTodelete(){
        Assert.assertTrue(true)
    }
}
```

I have this gradle configuration:

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

//Unit testing
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.3.0'
```

When I'm running my test, I have this error:

> $ adb shell am instrument -w -r    -e debug false -e class
> 'fr.tisseo.android.repository.productlocalization.tests.TodeleteTest'
> fr.tisseo.android.debug.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
> Connected to process 27190 on device 'google-pixel_3-89KX0AP57'.
>
> Started running tests
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> fr.tisseo.android.repository.productlocalization.tests.TodeleteTest

What did I missed during my implemantation?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue launching the AndroidTest target.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class .... on path: DexPathList[[zip file
```

I used Kotlin source code too. Adding `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'` to the Gradle configuration file solved my issue.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

...
```